# htaccess set cookie on first load without redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I am trying to use htaccess to make multi-language site and to translate something like site.com/de/path to site.com/path and set a cookie for language to "de" in this case. currently i have this solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{REQUEST_URI} !language=(en|de|fr|ar).*::\/\1\/.*
   RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$                         /$1/$2 [R,L,CO=language:$1:site.com:2678400:/]
 RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$                           /$2
```

But this is doing a redirect that i am willing to avoid for less traffic and more speed and also some crawlers might not like that.

So is there an other way to set this cookie on first load without redirecting?

Also i am curious why htaccess does not set the cookie directly on first load?

Note just setting the cookie without redirect as in the code below will make the cookie appears in php at second load of site:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$                         /$1/$2 [CO=language:$1:site.com:2678400:/]
```

Also preferably stick with cookies as using request parameters to send the language value to script might mess other links with parameters.

Further using env variable as an option seems to me as far fetched and not sure how it would affect the servers and its other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes simple descriptions can be misleading. Really, there is no such thing as "setting a cookie"; there is :

1. The server sending a `Set-Cookie: ...` header in the response to the browser, which it then stores
2. The browser finding a value in its store and sending a `Cookie: ...` header in the next request to the server

Neither of those things allow Apache (on the server) to send new cookie information to PHP (also on the server). The *only* cookies PHP will see are those *sent by the browser*; the first time a user visits your site, there will not be any.

So, you need to do something other than sending a `Set-Cookie` header, e.g.

- Have Apache set an environment variable, which *is* a communication between different processes on the server.
- Don't remove the language from the URL in the Apache configuration, instead detecting it in PHP, where you can *both* set the current language *and* [send a cookie to the browser](https://www.php.net/setcookie).

Comment: That explains for me why the cookie is not visible on first load.. Now setting environment variable would that visible only for the running script or it would also affect other sessions and page calls (other users)? or is that depending on server OS?

Comment: @fekirimalek Setting an environment variable would just be for that request.

Comment: "Don't remove the language from the URL" - I would second this. Removing the language code creates all sorts of problems with SEO. HOWEVER, that doesn't appear to be what @fekirimalek is doing. They are removing the language code prefix as part of an internal rewrite (not a redirect). It "looks like" they perhaps have a static file structure `/path/to/file.ext` to which they are adding a language prefix - the language prefix needs to be removed in order to serve the static file. (??)

Comment: @MrWhite Sure, and I'm saying don't remove it _even internally_ - pass the whole thing through to PHP, since you want PHP to know which language to serve.

Comment: I think @MrWhite is the closest to understand the situation here.. Indeed the structure is static and a single file will serve a content in the different languages depending on some variable that can be stored in cookies or session... This would be transparent for the browser... I will try with environment variable a check that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@IMSoP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914777/369434) that explains *why*.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{REQUEST_URI} !language=(en|de|fr|ar).*::\/\1\/.*
> RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R,L,CO=language:$1:site.com:2678400:/]
> ```
>
> ...and also some crawlers might not like that.

SE crawlers generally do not send cookies at all, so *depending* on a cookie to hold the language code is going to be problematic. The above rule (that looks at the cookie value and redirects to "correct" the cookie if it does not match the language code in the URL-path) will break SE crawlers (and any user that blocks or rejects cookies) - so the site will not be indexed.

The only reason (if at all) to set a language cookie should be to persist the user's chosen language between sessions. eg. On first visit and the language code prefix is missing from the URL?

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$ /$2
> ```

You are removing the language code prefix with an internal rewrite - so you are not actually changing the URL. I'm assuming this is necessary in order to be able to serve "static files"? eg. `/en/path/to/file.php` is internally rewritten to `/path/to/file.php` where the file actually resides? (Otherwise, I see no reason for this rule.)

There doesn't seem to be a need for cookies, environment variables or "language" URL parameters at all here since the language code can be read directly from the URL-path.

For example, in PHP, parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal:

```
<?php
preg_match('@^/(en|de|fr|ar)/@',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$matches);
$langCode = $matches[1] ?? null;
```

Comment: Well if i et good the points your are mentioning: crawlers will not be sending any cookies.. the first part of the the url is supposed to set that.. also /path/to/file.php has aleady the ability to render the content in the language set (how ever it is with cookies or session variables or any other way that can be passed to php).

Comment: @fekirimalek "the first part of the the url is supposed to set that.." - Yes, although not sure exactly what you mean by that. You can't set cookies on User-Agents/clients (ie. SE bots) that don't support cookies - you'll get an endless loop trying to do so. (As mentioned in IMSoP's answer, a cookie is sent from the client.) "or any other way that can be passed to php" - As mentioned in mine and IMSoP's answers, PHP can read the URL-path directly. I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: so I am setting this using environment variable now.. as this :RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$ /$2 [E=language:$1]
I see that passed to the script under $_SERVER[REDIRECT_language]. is that the normal behavior? I was more expecting it to be retrieved using $_ENV or getenv.

Comment: @fekirimalek Yes, you should be able to access the env var using `$_ENV` or `getenv()` in the same way you are accessing it via the `$_SERVER` superglobal. The `REDIRECT_` prefix comes about through looping by the rewrite engine and depends on the directives you have the `.htaccess` file. I see you've [asked another question regarding the `REDIRECT_` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929096/htaccess-set-environment-variable-adds-redirect-prefix-to-name) so further discussion on this should continue there.