# htaccess set environment variable adds REDIRECT_ prefix to name

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables, centos7

I am trying to set an environment variable depending on the request url in .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$ /$2 [E=language:$1]
```

This seems to work but in php a REDIRECT_ prefix is added one or 2 times to the variable name: ***REDIRECT_REDIRECT_language*** or ***REDIRECT_language***

So the questions are: why that prefix is added? and how to avoid this? to get the environment variable as named.

the server is Centos 7.

EDIT:
for @MrWhite, I can't post the entire file structure here but this is how my htaccess looks like:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    
    # ----------------------------------------------------
    # server's settings
    php_value memory_limit 200M
    php_value max_file_uploads 99
    php_value post_max_size 400M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
    
    # ----------------------------------------------------
    # Enable gzip
    
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    # For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    # Régles d'interdiction du listage
     Options -Indexes
     ErrorDocument 400                                           /common/page_not_found.php
     ErrorDocument 401                                           /common/page_not_found.php
     ErrorDocument 403                                           /common/page_not_found.php
     ErrorDocument 404                                           /common/page_not_found.php
     ErrorDocument 500                                           /common/page_not_found.php
    
     RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*)$ /$2 [E=language:$1]
     RewriteRule ^$                                             /ind.php [END]
    
     RewriteRule ^tm/(.*)$                                      /tmp/$1 [END]
     RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$                                     /test.php$1 [END]
```

The two last lines are actually how all other rules look like, always with ***END*** flag. I was preferring to avoid any re-passes to keep it readble.. but it seems my server has other view :-)

I added the last line for testing with this url **http://192.168.2.100/de/test/** for an actual script test.php.. I see that $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]=/test.php so the rewriting is good but i still get REDIRECT_REDIRECT_language=en

Answer (score 1):

The `REDIRECT_` prefix is added in a *directory* context when the rewrite engine "starts over" (effectively "loops"). At the start of the next pass by the rewrite engine, any environment variables that exist in the previous phase are prefixed with `REDIRECT_`. This continues for every pass by the rewrite engine (eg. `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_language` etc.).

Precisely why/how this happens depends on the directives you have in the `.htaccess` file (and `<Directory>` containers in the server config). So, in order to see why this is happening and how it can perhaps be avoided we would need to see your entire `.htaccess` file, together with the URL(s) you are requesting and the expected response. (But otherwise, this is an expected side effect of using environment variables and mod_rewrite in a *directory* context.)

Without knowing your existing directives and the intention of the rule you've posted (eg. is this intended to map to a physical file? Although if it is then you should probably test for the existence of that file first) it's hard to say, but this rule should probably include the `L` flag at least or `END` (Apache 2.4) to prevent a second pass by the rewrite engine (when the env vars are renamed). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|ar)/(.*) /$2 [E=language:$1,END]
```

---

*Aside:*

Depending on your server config, you may be able to access the "top-level" var using the following in PHP:

```
<?php
$value = apache_getenv('language',true);
```

Comment: "Depending on your server config" If you're running mod_php this will work, but if you're running FPM or some other form of fastCGI it will not.

Comment: @MrWhite, I made some edits to add extract from the htaccess file. Aside i also trying to avoid changing the config as much i can.. if there is no solution I will be testing for the variable with prefixes in loop of php script.